# What does $ with a numeric value mean in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, char

What does it means, in Delphi, when I see a command like this:

```
char($23)
```

What does the dollar symbol mean in this context?

Comment: It is also possible to write the above as `#$23`  (# means character literal, and $23 still means hex value equivalent to 35 decimal)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The dollar symbol represents that the following is a hex value.

ShowMessage(Char($23)); shows #.

Comment: Basically the same as 0x23 in C based languages (C, C++, C#, Java). StrToInt can also convert '$23' to int 35

Answer (score 2):

The `$` symbol is used to prefix a hexadecimal literal. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements_(Delphi)#Numerals) says:

> **Numerals**
>
> Integer and real constants can be represented in decimal notation as
>   sequences of digits without commas or spaces, and prefixed with the +
>   or - operator to indicate sign. Values default to positive (so that,
>   for example, 67258 is equivalent to +67258) and must be within the
>   range of the largest predefined real or integer type.
>
> Numerals with decimal points or exponents denote reals, while other
>   numerals denote integers. When the character E or e occurs within a
>   real, it means "times ten to the power of". For example, 7E2 means 7 *
>   10^2, and 12.25e+6 and 12.25e6 both mean 12.25 * 10^6.
>
> The dollar-sign prefix indicates a hexadecimal numeral, for example,
>   $8F. Hexadecimal numbers without a preceding - unary operator are
>   taken to be positive values. During an assignment, if a hexadecimal
>   value lies outside the range of the receiving type an error is raised,
>   except in the case of the **Integer** (32-bit integer) where a warning
>   is raised. In this case, values exceeding the positive range for
>   **Integer** are taken to be negative numbers in a manner consistent with two's complement integer representation.

So, in your example, `$23` is the number whose hexadecimal representation is `23`. That number has decimal representation `35`, so you can write:

```
Assert($23 = 35);
```

Answer (score 1):

It represents a character. For example char(13) is end of line.

Comment: THe whole thing (Char included) means a character, but since the title asked about the $ alone (I reworded it) this answer is not as good as the accepted one.